# Jquery Ajax success function never called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myBaseUrl + 'Products/addItemToBasket',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        id: window.location.pathname.substring(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
        amount: amount
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var dat = JSON.parse(data);
       }
    }
});
```

Now this calls the following method in php:

```
    public function addItemToBasket()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //todo delete efter at have insat fancybox med valg af antal styk. (sendes via ajax).
            $shopping = null;
            $item = $this->Product->find('first',array('conditions' => array('Product.id' =>$this->request->data['id'])));
        if(isset($_SESSION['basket'])){
            $shopping =  $_SESSION['basket'];
        }else{
            $shopping = array();
        }
        array_push($shopping,$item);
        $_SESSION['basket'] = $shopping;
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['basket']);
    }
}
```

When i try to debug it everything is working (it gets into the php function) and updates my `$_SESSION` variable.

BUT it never runs the success function and it never alerts the data.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Should you be echoing `json_encode . . .` ?

Comment: your usage of this->request->is('post') is leading me to believe that this is a cakephp app.  if it is, then just an echo is not going to dump the output, you will have to actually output this in the associated view.  also taggin this with cakephp might help too.

Comment: What if you just alert("TEST") or set a breakpoint?  Are you sure it's not entering the success function?

Comment: @johnnymonster then what is?

Comment: Well have you added a `.fail()` callback to see what's wrong? I suspect that the returned json cannot be correctly parsed.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Nothing is alerted.

Comment: @Jeffman changed to encode sorry!

Comment: In other words, an alert doesn't occur. *"Nothing is alerted"* somewhat suggests an alert happened but was blank, which is likely not the case.

Comment: Ok so further looking at your ajax setup.  You have it requiring json.    without you giving any more information about your cakephp app, like the view setup etc. I am going to assume you are just dumping the default view, which is not json, thus would never make it to the success callback in your javascript.

Comment: Additionally, you don't need to do a JSON.parse in your success as the response will already be parsed by jquery.

Comment: @johnnymonster is it possible you can post an example on how to do ajax in cake?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen there are a few ways to output json data from cake. The easiest way would be to create a blank layout and a view file that echo's out your array as json.  the second way would be to use json/xml data views.  its a little more complicated but here is the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: Are you sending correct headers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-content-type-http-header-for-json

Comment: Check once with console.log() in success function.

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE: I know this question is from a couple of months ago, but any help will be useful for people looking for answers to this kind of problems.*

As far as I know, because I'm running with a similar problem, it all depends on the response you get from the webservice (you can check it out with Chrome debugging console). For instance, I'm getting this now:

- readyState: 4
- statusText: "OK"
- responseText: (The result I am looking for)

The problem is, as you say, I always get to run the Error part of the callback, never the Success, even if I'm getting the right responseText. As I've read, that's because the call to the WS was OK, but the parsing from JSON wasn't, so it calls "error".

So far I don't know how to fix it, but maybe this will give a clue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do only answer if you are fairly sure to answer the question.

Comment: Got it! I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.
Thanks for the advice.